# Async issue regarding types

Tags: c#, sql, asynchronous, dapper

I have recently switched from Entity Framework To Dapper.  So far I am really pleased with the results; however, I am having an async issue though that I'm having difficulty resolving.

An example is the following:

```
var list1 = await _db.getList(...);   // async Task<Element> getList(...)
var list2 = v_list1.select( async item => {

  var flag = await _db.getFlagValue(...); // async Task<bool> getFlagValue(...)
  item.flag = flag;
  return item;

});
```

because of the "async" before 'item' typeof list2 is `IEnumerable<Task<Element>>` instead of `IEnumerable<Element>`.

If I change getFlagValue to be sync instead of async and change the code then it works fine.

I tried adding an additional

```
.Select( async r => await r );
```

to the end but it didnt work.  Though the typeof for list2 was correct, the it hung at runtime.

Hopefully I have provided enough code to show the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `await Task.WhenAll(list2)`.

`Task.WhenAll()` takes a collection of tasks and returns a task of a collection of results.

Comment: thank you.  That worked.  Now, if you will excuse me, I'm going to go beat my head against the wall for not thinking of that.